# Rotate in Postscript with center of object as reference

Tags: postscript

Assume that I have a square object in postscript. How do I rotate the square with the center of the square as the reference angle, instead of the bottom left corner of the square ?

Comment: translate the origin to the centre of the square, perform the rotation. Draw the square. You'll probably want to gsave and grestore round that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your square is still being plotted from its lower left corner, then Ken's comment gives the general idea, but also you'll need to undo the translation after rotating.

```
/Sq {0 0 moveto 0 100 lineto 100 100 lineto 100 0 lineto closepath} def

gsave

50 50 translate
45 rotate
-50 -50 translate
Sq stroke

grestore
```